# Why are curl and file_get_contents returning 404 on cloudlinux?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am pulling some content in to a text file and than using curl or file_get_contents to display it

Here it works perfectly fine
http://www.dev.phosting.eu/

but here
it returns 404 
http://dev5.gozenhost.com/index.php/shortcodes/114-testing

and the file is accessible 
http://dev5.gozenhost.com/media/plg_system_yjsg/yjsgparsed/raw-githubusercontent-com/yjsgframework/demo-docs/master/shortcodes/Icons.txt

`$getContent`   returns the accessible link above , and this is curl.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getContent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data     = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

if (empty($data)) {

    $content = 'Error processing url. ' . $httpCode;

} else if ($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 300) {



    if ($local) {


        $content = $data;


    } else {

        $content = yjsg_clean_html($data);
        JFile::write($filepath, $content);

    }


} else {

    $content = 'Error processing url.' . $httpCode;
}
```

I mean all files are in the right places , and accessible
Funny thing is if I use `curl` or `file_get_contents` to access someone else site it works fine , if I am accessing file on my own domain it fails. Again only on cloudlinux.

Does anyone know what the issue is and possible fix . 
Thank you!

Comment: One of the hosts allows remote fopen, and one doesn't.

Comment: u mean allow_url_fopen?  curl needs it?

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't see that you only experience this problem on your own domain. If it's on your own domain, why aren't you just opening the file?

Comment: what do u mean just open the file?

Comment: He means, why are you using HTTP to access it via URL, instead of just accessing it via the local file system of the server (if it is an actual file)?

Comment: sometimes we need 10 brains to figure simple things out. thnx!